# Redirecting to another page in ASP.NET MVC using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect from one page to another page in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 using JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax. On button click event I have written JavaScript code like below.

```
function foo(id)
{
    $.post('/Branch/Details/' + id);
}
```

My controller code is like this:

```
public ViewResult Details(Guid id)
{
     Branch branch = db.Branches.Single(b => b.Id == id);
     return View(branch);
}
```

When I click on a button it is calling the Details action inside  BranchController, but it doesn't return to the Details view.

I didn't get any error or exception. It's showing status 200 OK in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29). What is wrong in my code and how can I redirect to the Details view page?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You are not subscribing to any success callback in your $.post AJAX call.  Meaning that the request is executed, but you do nothing with the results. If you want to do something useful with the results, try:

```
$.post('/Branch/Details/' + id, function(result) {
    // Do something with the result like for example inject it into
    // some placeholder and update the DOM.
    // This obviously assumes that your controller action returns
    // a partial view otherwise you will break your markup
});
```

On the other hand if you want to redirect, you absolutely do not need AJAX. You use AJAX only when you want to stay on the same page and update only a portion of it.

So if you only wanted to redirect the browser:

```
function foo(id) {
    window.location.href = '/Branch/Details/' + id;
}
```

As a side note: 
You should never be hardcoding urls like this. You should always be using url helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. So:

```
function foo(id) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Branch", new { id = "__id__" })';
    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Darin. 
I am using url helper as you suggested but its error on page because url is something like this http://localhost/@Url.Action(%22Details%22,%20%22Branch%22,%20new%20%7B%20id%20=%20%2244eaf010-50a8-4e75-87b7-80b3734b79ef%22%20%7D)
How to get proper Url from this helper.

Comment: @Sharad, is this in a separate javascript file? If it is you cannot use url helpers in it. You could define `url` as a global variable inside your view: `<script type="text/javascript">var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Branch", new { id = "__id__" })';</script>`. And then you can use it in your separate javascript file.

Comment: yes this is in a seperate JS file. I placed it in master page and now its working. Thanks a lot @Darin.

Comment: Doesn't a windows.location.href do a GET?  If so, the original question is trying to do a POST.  I'm surprised this was marked as answered because there is a large difference between the two.

Comment: how to use the last approach in case of multiple parameters?

Answer (score 48):

This could be done by using a hidden variable in the view and then using that variable to post from the JavaScript code.

Here is my code in the view

```
@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));
```

Now you can use this in the JavaScript file as:

```
 var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
 location.href = url;
```

It worked like a charm fro me. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: For my situation this answer is superior, because I wanted to grab the Primary Key from the Model (i.e. Model.WorkFlowID) to include into the redirection. Like this:    @Html.Hidden("RedirectTo",Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", Model.WorkFlowID));

Comment: rather: @Html.Hidden("RedirectTo",Url.Action("Edit","WorkFlows",new { id = Model.WorkFlowID }));

Comment: This helped me so much! Thanks!!! I was trying to use a modal view to redirect pages in MVC, and was struggling. Appreciate it.

Comment: This works for me (ASP.NET MVC). window.location.href doesn't

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
window.location.href = '/Branch/Details/' + id;
```

But your Ajax code is incomplete without success or error functions.

Answer (score 6):

```
// in the HTML code I used some razor
@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("Action", "Controller"));

// now down in the script I do this
<script type="text/javascript">

var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.UserFriendlyErrMsg === 'Some Message') {
                // display a prompt
                alert("Message: " + result.UserFriendlyErrMsg);
                // redirect us to the new page
                location.href = url;
            }
            $('#friendlyMsg').html(result.UserFriendlyErrMsg);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lnkLogout_Confirm()
    {
        var bResponse = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?');

        if (bResponse === true) {
            ////console.log("lnkLogout_Confirm clciked.");
            var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Login")';
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        return bResponse;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

check the code below this will be helpful for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.opener.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "EventstController")', window.close();
</script>
```