# mvc 4, How to open (new page) HttpPost view controller? with model data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Administracion(Usuario usuario)
{
    var tupla = new Tuple<Usuario>(usuario) { };
    return View(tupla);

}
```

Now in Jquery I have the Usuario Object, 
I only want to call (no change to httpget) to Administracion function in controller for return the view.

this would be something similar to execute
`@Html.ActionLink` but with httpost and model data

What I want, then?
**simply load a new "page/view" of type httpost with model using jquery**

its required it would be with jquery (where I have the Usuario object)

Comment: what library do you have for your modal dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
            url: "../yourController/Administracion",
            dataType: "text",
            data:  {Usuario : data},
   success: function(result){
        // replace your return data on div
   },
 error: function(xhr){
        alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
 });
```

Comment: but then, the page wouldn't be in a new (url)page, this would continue with the same url page por example if before of execute the ajax was in www.mypage.com/usuario/login and execute the ajax, the UI would change but  the link of page would not, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is ... try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148632/redirecting-to-another-page-in-asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-jquery