# How to redirect to a view from controller while using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

I want to display a string using XMLHttpRequest in ASP.NET MVC . 
I am unable to redirect to "PageReceiving" View from the "PageSending" View using the below code. "PageReceiving2" is just a dummy actionMethod which redirectToAction to "PageReceiving" View, but in the browser, its not redirecting to the "PageReceiving" View instead it remains on "PageSending" View.

**Here is my View:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "PageSending";
```

}

PageSending

#### Enter Text

```
@*<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
<script>
  //  $(document).ready(
    function loadXML() {
       // alert("hello");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/Test/PageReceiving2", false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                //  alert(xhttp.response);
                //location.href = "/Test/PageReceiving?Name=" + name;
            }
        }
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

        xhttp.send("Name=" + name);
    }
</script>
```

**Here is the Controller:**

```
  using ProjectMVC1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace ProjectMVC1.Controllers
{



public class TestController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Test/

        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        public ActionResult PageSending()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PageReceiving2(Student stu)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("PageReceiving", new Student { Name = stu.Name });

            }
        public ActionResult PageReceiving(Student stu)
        {

            return View(stu);


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting back from the server? Assuming you uncommented the `location.href` line, it should work, but only if `readystate` is 4 and `status` is 200. If you're getting a 500, for example, then nothing is going to happen here. You can use your browser's developer console to see the raw response from the AJAX call. That said, redirecting after an AJAX call is pointless. If you're going to redirect anyways, *don't use AJAX*. Just do a standard form post and call it a day.

Comment: Uncommenting the "location.href" line, it is working, but i wanted to do redirect from the controller actionMethods, isn't that possible? Or is it because this is an AJAX call, so it is not possible(I know that its pointless to redirect after an AJAX call, but i was unaware that this is an AJAX call..pardon me). @ChrisPratt

Comment: Leave it. I found out about it being AJAX, it was a silly question, it may help someone in future who get stuck similarly.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Pratt has suggested, doing a Ajax call to redirect to some other action is absolutely pointless. From your code, it is not at all clear what is done with the data returned from the server.

Even then, if you want to redirect to some other action, you can call a function like this -

```
function foo(id) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Branch", new { id = "__id__" })';
    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
}
```

Reference - Darin Dimitrov's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148632/redirecting-to-another-page-in-asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-jquery/8148657#8148657).